# removeTracksFromPlaylist not removing tracks with ios spotify sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify, playlist

I was testing this method to remove tracks from a playlist. Basically I modified the demo project "simple track playback" provided with the SDK. I wanted to remove the track form the playlist when you hit fastForward. I changed the fastForward method this way but it's not doing anything, and error is nil.

```
-(IBAction)fastForward:(id)sender {
    if([self.player isPlaying] && self.currentPlaylistSnapshot){
        SPTAuth *auth = [SPTAuth defaultInstance];
        [self.currentPlaylistSnapshot removeTracksFromPlaylist:@[self.player.currentTrackURI]
                                    withAccessToken:auth.session.accessToken
                                    callback:^(NSError *error) {
                                        if (error != nil) {
                                            NSLog(@"*** Failed to remove track : %@", self.titleLabel.text);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }];
    }

    [self.player skipNext:nil];
}
```

`self.currentPlaylistSnapshot` is the one I've got from the `handleNewSession` method.

There's also a static method apparently offering something similar which I have't tried yet.

```
createRequestForRemovingTracks:fromPlaylist:withAccessToken:snapshot:error:
```

According to the documentation both options are implemented asynchronously and will take seconds to reflect the results in the server but I'm suspecting that there's either something wrong or I'm just missing to do an actual request to push the changes on the local snapshot maybe?

Documentation:
https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTPlaylistSnapshot.html#//api/name/removeTracksWithPositionsFromPlaylist:withAccessToken:callback:

ios sdk:
https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by reseting simulator + adding **SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope** (which I fogot to do...)

```
auth.requestedScopes = @[SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope];
```